# How to hide the "Title Bar" using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have 4 different activities on my app, in 2 of them it shows a white Title bar (with activity or package name) above my custom toolbar, but in other 2 this bar is hidden by the custom one.

I want to show only my custom toolbar and hide the default...

this is my "styles.xml" code:

```
 <resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/secondaryColor</item>
    <item name ="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">

    <item name="android:background">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Make sure all your activies does not override the atribute theme, since you will be usiing theme into application tag

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I tried to remove this atribute from my activities, and I tried to keep it too, and it doesn't work anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]

I just change the class my Activities was inheriting from AppCompatActivity to FragmentActivity (until now I have no issues came from this change)